# How to use resource option of user page in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have tried to use resource instead of get and post in user page .

Url :

```
<a href="mybalance"></i><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Balance</a>
```

Route :

```
Route::resource('mybalance',  'RechargeController');
```

Controller :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
     $id= $request->user()->id;
     $user = User::find($id);
     //$id = Auth::user()->id;
     //$request = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
     //dd($id); exit;

     return view('frontend.balance.index',compact('user'));
}
```

But the link could not work. How to deals with this error?

Comment: Did the below answer solve your problem or are you still having issues with the link? If it did solve you issue please may you mark it as accepted. :) Otherwise can you leave a comment saying why it didn't help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this issue is because the link you have is relative i.e. it doesn't start with `http://`, `https://` or even `/`.

You have a few options to achieve what you're after. You could imply change the link to `/mybalance`, however, depending on how your application is set up this may not work.

I would recommend using one of the helpers that come with Laravel e.g.

**[url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url)**:

```
<a href="{{ url('mybalance') }}">
```

or since you're using `resource` a route name will also be created so you could use **[route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route)**:

```
<a href="{{ route('mybalance.index') }}">
```

To check your route names you can run `php artisan route:list`